# Issue with combination of \includemedia and animateinline environment

Tags: beamer, animations, animate, media9

We recently observed an issue with a beamer document including multiple animations. On one slide an mp4 movie was embedded using `\includemedia` and on another slide an image series was animated using the `animateinline` environment. When including the `controls` option in the `animateinline` environment, no error message was produced but the animation produced by the `animateinline` environment would not play, the mp4 embedded by `\includemedia` was fine though. As soon as we omitted the `controls` option everything would play as expected.

Is this an know issue? Does any body else had the same issue? Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. Please provide us with a [Minimal Compiling Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that demonstrates the problem.